# Queuing and dispatching long simulations

Tags: python, queue

I am developing a Python module to manage the execution of long-baseline simulation processes. Whilst I have had some successes to date, I would like to improve it in order to make it more usable for its intended, er, *users*.

My code to date uses `sys`, `time`, `subprocess` and the package `watchdog`; it monitors a folder for new run files, places these in a FIFO queue and executes them simultaneously up to a pre-defined limit. This works, but is a bit clunky, and managing this dynamically is impractical.

*I am not a computer scientist or a software engineer*; this is why I am asking for help. Despite that, I am confident that I would be able to do the (bulk of the) coding work, but I would like some guidance on:

- What are the computer science-y names for some of the concepts I'm describing
- What packages are out there for doing some of these things in Python 3.x
- What approaches you would use to do these things
- What data structures you might use to do this

I appreciate any help you're able to offer, and of course please let me know if there is a better StackExchange site where I could submit this question. Thank you in advance!

---

Some detail about the simulations:

- Entirely based in Windows 10
- One of three or four different varieties
- Executed from command line with reference to an input file
- Simulations either fail instantly or almost instantly, or run for several hours, days or even weeks
- Typical batches are up to tens of simulations
- Simulations use lots of RAM and an entire CPU

I should also point out that, according to the terms of the simulation software licenses, I am expressly forbidden to use third-party cloud computing platforms.

Here's what I need the module to do:

- Simulations dispatched automatically
- Simultaneous simulations up to a limit
- Queue runs indefinitely
- Queue can be added to dynamically (reference in a new file)
- Feedback on what's running and what's in the queue
- First in, first out queuing

And some extra ideas, from users, about what would be *nice to have*:

- Can dispatch simulations onto multiple computers
- Simultaneous simulation limit could be changed dynamically
- System of prioritisation
- Simulations can be terminated early
- If the module crashes, can be restarted without having to rebuild the queue
- A browser-based interface where the queue could be viewed / managed

Comment: What you want seems to be some sort of general-purpose job runner. You may want to look into Airflow, apscheduler, Celery, Dask, etc.

Comment: These seem like great solutions. It would be helpful to have some kind of comparison of features, usage cases, advantages and disadvantages - for the uninitiated! Thank you for your answer though.